# How do I scrape the subscriberCount from Youtube API through apps script on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube-api, google-apis-explorer

This what I have so far:

```
function YoutubeScraper() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var activeSheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet()
  var search = YouTube.Search.list("snippet, id", {q: "pizza", maxResults: 50})
  var results = search.items.map((item) => [item.id.videoId, item.snippet.title, item.snippet.publishedAt, item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url])
  var ids = results.map((id) => id[0]).join(",")
  var stats = YouTube.Videos.list("statistics", {id: ids})
  var videoStats = stats.items.map((item) => [item.statistics.viewCount, item.statistics.likeCount, item.statistics.dislikeCount])
  activeSheet.getRange(2,1,results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results)
  activeSheet.getRange(2,3, videoStats.length, results[0].length).setValues(videoStats)
}
```

I tried adding item.statistics.subscriberCount in

```
var videoStats = stats.items.map((item) => [item.statistics.viewCount, item.statistics.likeCount, item.statistics.dislikeCount])
```

but it does not work. There's a note on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#common-use-cases that says that " statistics.subscriberCount property value has been updated to reflect a YouTube policy change that affects the way that subscriber counts are displayed". What can I do to get the subscriberCount? The output should be a data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I thought that in your situation, in order to retrieve the value of `subscriberCount`, the method of "Channels: list" will be used like `YouTube.Channels.list`. Also, your provided URL of official document is for the method of "Channels: list".
- But in your script, `YouTube.Videos.list` is used. I thought that this might be the reason fo your issue.
- In your script, I thought that you wanted to put the values of `subscriberCount` to the same row of the channel ID. But, in your current script, `results` has 4 columns. But `videoStats` is put from the column "C". In this case, the columns "C" and "D" are overwritten.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function YoutubeScraper() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var activeSheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
  var search = YouTube.Search.list("snippet", { q: "pizza", maxResults: 50 });
  var results = search.items.map((item) => [item.snippet.channelId, item.snippet.title, item.snippet.publishedAt, item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url]);
  var ids = results.map((id) => id[0]).join(",");
  var stats = YouTube.Channels.list("statistics", { id: ids });
  var videoStats = stats.items.map((item) => [item.id, item.statistics.viewCount, item.statistics.subscriberCount]).reduce((o, [id, ...v]) => Object.assign(o, {[id]: v}));
  results = results.map(e => videoStats[e[0]] ? e.concat(videoStats[e[0]]) : e.concat(Array(2).fill("")));
  activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

- In this modification, the values of `videoStats` are converted to an object for searching the channel ID. And, using the object, each value is pushed to the corresponding row of `results`. And then, the values are put to the active sheet.
- At `YouTube.Channels.list`, there are no properties of `item.statistics.likeCount, item.statistics.dislikeCount`.

#### Reference:

- [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> that issue has not been completely resolved. What I am trying to do is to get all the information I can, from YouTube.Seach: channelId, videoId, title of the video, when it was published and the thumbnail. From YouTube.Videos: the number of likes, dislikes views and comments. From YouTube.Channels: the overall number of views of the channels and the number of subscribers
> How about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```
function YoutubeScraper2() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var activeSheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Retrieve YouTube.Search.list.
  var search = YouTube.Search.list("snippet", { q: "pizza", maxResults: 50 });
  var results = search.items.map((item) => [item.snippet.channelId, item.id.videoId, item.snippet.title, item.snippet.publishedAt, item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url]);
  
  // Retrieve channel IDs and video IDs.
  var {channelIds, videoIds} = results.reduce((o, [channelId, videoId]) => {
    o.channelIds.push(channelId);
    o.videoIds.push(videoId);
    return o;
  }, {channelIds: [], videoIds: []});

  // Retrieve YouTube.Videos.list.
  var videoList = YouTube.Videos.list("statistics", {id: videoIds.join(",")});
  var videoStats = videoList.items.map((item) => [item.id, item.statistics.viewCount, item.statistics.likeCount, item.statistics.dislikeCount]).reduce((o, [id, ...v]) => Object.assign(o, {[id]: v}), {});

  // Retrieve YouTube.Channels.list
  var channelList = YouTube.Channels.list("statistics", { id: channelIds.join(",") });
  var channelStats = channelList.items.map((item) => [item.id, item.statistics.viewCount, item.statistics.subscriberCount]).reduce((o, [id, ...v]) => Object.assign(o, {[id]: v}), {});

  // Create an array for putting values and put the values to Spreadsheet.
  results = results.map(e => channelStats[e[0]] ? e.concat(channelStats[e[0]]) : e.concat(Array(2).fill("")));
  results = results.map(e => videoStats[e[1]] ? e.concat(videoStats[e[1]]) : e.concat(Array(3).fill("")));
  var header = ["channelId", "videoId", "title", "publishedAt", "thumbnails", "viewCount", "subscriberCount", "viewCount", "likeCount", "dislikeCount"];
  results.unshift(header);
  activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

- When above script is run, the columns `channelId, videoId, title, publishedAt, thumbnails, viewCount, subscriberCount, viewCount, likeCount, dislikeCount` are put to the active sheet.
- If you don't want to put the header, please modify the last 3 lines to `activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results);`.
- If you want to arrange the columns, please modify above script.

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following Spreadsheet is obtained.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the input! You were right, I needed to specify YouTube.Channels.list to get access to the subscriberCount. However, I did `var stats = YouTube.Videos.list("statistics", {id: ids})
  var videoStats = stats.items.map((item) => [item.statistics.viewCount, item.statistics.likeCount, item.statistics.dislikeCount])` because I also want the number of likes, dislikes and comments from the video

Comment: @Ernesto Figueroa Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying and the current situation, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. So, can I ask you about whether your issue could be resolved? If my answer was still not resolve your issue, I apologize. At that time, please tell me the detail of it. By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike! No need to apologize. Thank you for you help

Comment: that issue has not been completely resolved. What I am trying to do is to get all the information I can, from YouTube.Seach: channelId, videoId, title of the video, when it was published and the thumbnail. From YouTube.Videos: the number of likes, dislikes views and comments. From YouTube.Channels:  the overall number of views of the channels and the number of subscribers.

Comment: @Ernesto Figueroa Thank you for replying. From your replying, I added one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: that is exactly what I was expecting! Thank you so much!